# write: Invalid argument

Tags: android, linux

I am writing a native executable binary in C, which will write the android device node: `/sys/class/leds/lcd-brightness/brightness`. push it to `/system/bin` and run as root.

However, system call `write` will return error message: "write: Invalid argument"

The code is as below:

```
// set background brightness
int bfd = open("/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness", O_WRONLY);

if(bfd < 0 ) {
    perror("open");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("bfd: %d\n", bfd);
printf("*p: %d\n", (int)*p);
if(write(bfd, p, 1) < 0) {
    free(p);
    perror("write");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
close(bfd);
close(fd);
```

p is a pointer to the data, I print *p before write, and it's all right.

`/sys/class/leds/lcd-brightness/brightness` has the following file permission:

```
-rw-rw-rw 1 system system 4096 2018-04-18 18:46 brightness
```

And I can override this file successfully with following command in adb shell as root

```
echo 100 > /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness
```

What's wrong with my code ? I have struggled with this issue for hours. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: is your app has root permission ???

Comment: @RohitChauhan, Yes, the executable has root permission.

Comment: try using O_DIRECT Flag

Comment: @RohitChauhan, I tried the O_DIRECT flag, It did't work

Comment: take look at my answer

Comment: It's very weird, I can write the device node successful using `system` function: `system("echo 100 > /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness")`, But why ? I am totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be permission that's why You need to set flag for writing file

Below are the diffrent flags you have to set.

Try this Code

```
int bfd = open("/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | S_IWUSR |S_IXUSR |S_IXOTH);
```

1. `S_IRUSR` Set read rights for the owner to true.
2. `S_IWUSR` Set write rights for the owner to true.
3. `S_IXUSR` Set execution rights for the owner to true.
4. `S_IRGRP` Set read rights for the group to true.
5. `S_IWGRP` Set write rights for the group to true.
6. `S_IXGRP` Set execution rights for the group to true.
7. `S_IROTH` Set read rights for other users to true.
8. `S_IWOTH` Set write rights for other users to true.
9. `S_IXOTH` Set execution rights for other users to true.

Hope This helps

Answer (score 0):

Sysfs attributes expect data in a string format, i.e., an array of char null-terminated. From your code, it seems that you are passing to write a pointer to an integer:

> `printf("*p: %d\n", (int)*p);`

Try something like:

```
int ret;
int bfd;
char p_str[24];

int bfd = open("/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness", O_WRONLY);
if (bfd < 0) {
    /* handle the error */
}

snprintf(p_str, sizeof p_str, "%i", p);

ret = write(bfd, p_str, sizeof(p_str));
if (ret < 0) {
    /* handle the error */
}
```